# Help with substitutions in multiple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, substitution

I am in the middle of a homework problem and can't find out what I am doing wrong. The question asks:

> Use the transformation in Exercise 2 (given as $u=x+2y$, $v=x-y$) to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{3}}\int_{y}^{2-2y}(x+2y)e^{y-x}dxdy$ by first writing the integral over a region G in the $u v$-plane.

My work is as follows:

Finding x and y in terms of u and v: I found that $x=\frac{u}{3}+\frac{2}{3}v$ and that $y=\frac{u}{3}-\frac{v}{3}$

> My work for the above: $v=x-y$   ->   $y=x-v$
>
> $v=x+2y$ -> $x=u-2y$
>
> $x=u-2(x-v) = u-2x+2v \equiv 3x=u+2v = \frac{u}{3} + \frac{2}{3}$
>
> $y=u-2y-v\equiv3y=u-v=\frac{u}{3}-\frac{v}{3}$

Then finding the Jacobian using the coefficients of the aforementioned x and y equivalents: \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \\[0.3em]
\frac{1}{3} &-\frac{1}{3} 
\end{bmatrix} $=-\frac{7}{9}$

Solving for the bounds and equation in terms of $u$ and $v$: $\int_{0}^{\frac{2}{3}}\int_{0}^{2}(u)e^{-v}(-\frac{7}{9})dudv$

The answer I get is $-\frac{14}{9}(1-\frac{1}{e^\frac{2}{3}})$, which is not what the answer is supposed to be: $\frac{1}{3}(1+\frac{3}{e^2})$

Comment: Be careful: the expressions for $x$ and $y$ you found do not satisfy $v=x-y$.

Comment: For the Jacobian , you have to take the absolute value .

Comment: I'm not sure what I did wrong with my math for finding x and y relative to u and v. I'll edit the above to show my work step by step for that part.

Comment: I checked $x$ and  $y$,  in terms of $u$ and  $v$, they are correct. I think the problem is in the boundary of the integral when taking  $u$ and  $v$

Comment: Finding the boundaries is always the part I get stuck up on the most. Could you possibly point out where I went wrong with that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your computation of $u$ and  $v$ in terms of  $x$ and  $y$ is correct. However your the determinant of your Jacobian is  $- \frac{1}{3}$  so  its absolute value is  $ \frac{1}{3}$   (Easy to check that) .

Now for your boundaries . In the first integral you have  $$  0 \leq y \leq  2/3 $$  and  $$ y \leq x\leq  2-2y$$ so in terms of  $u$ and  $v$ we get  $$  0 \leq \frac{u-v}{3} \leq  2/3 $$  and  $$ \frac{u-v}{3}   \leq \frac{u+2v}{3} \leq  2-2\frac{u-v}{3} $$ 
The first one implies $$ v \leq  u \leq 2+v $$ qnd the second implies  $$  u-v \leq  u+2v  \text{ and } u+2v \leq 6-2u+2v$$  and so  treating these last two inequalities we get  $$  -v \leq  2v  \text{ and } u\leq 6-2u $$  i.e.   $$  3v \geq 0  \text{ and } 3u\leq 6 $$ so that   $$  v \geq 0  \text{ and } u\leq 2 $$ plotting this region we get [image] 
so you integral  should be  $$\frac{1}{3 } \int_0^2 \int_0^u u e^{-v}dvdu$$
Try to compute it, and you will find the desired result. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I might ask, what program did you use to plot that?

Comment: I use http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ4XjIiLCJjb2xvciI6IiMwMDAwMDAifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDB9XQ-- to plot the two main function, then  I edit edit using "paint"  in window to add colors and color the region .